# new MsBuildSonarQube runner - fxcop exited with code 1

Tags: sonarqube, fxcop, sonar-runner, msbuild-4.0

I have been facing an issue with New MSBuildSonarRunner Component. I am using it for my .net project(s) analysis.  Recently , I have activated some fxcop rules into my quality profile. When I run analysis on a project, it shows an error - "sonar.cs.fxcop.assembly must be set".

I am using Sonarqube 5.1.1 & Fxcop10.0 is already installed. I have changed SonarQube.Analysis.Xml file and SET below two properties.

sonar.cs.fxcop.fxCopCmdPath = C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Fxcop 10.0\FxCopCmd.exe

sonar.fxcop.installDirectory=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Fxcop 10.0\

I  don't see any use with these settings. I understand that even error message is also not talking about above settings.

What value I must give to "sonar.cs.fxcop.assembly" ?  Where should I specify this settings - In configuration file ? or .csproj file ?

I have  checked [SO post by @Dinesh][1][How to use FxCop analysis with the new MsBuild Sonar runner?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32142494/how-to-use-fxcop-analysis-with-the-new-msbuild-sonar-runner)
It is mentioned in the post that FXCOP is natively supported. But it is not happening.

Did any one face/resolve this issue ? It has stopped our sonarqube benefits.

Comment: I have tried with setting assembly path for "sonar.cs.fxcop.assembly". 

sonar.cs.fxcop.assembly= raj\MKS\VS\MKS\bin\Debug\ABC.dll

But new runner is looking for the assembly in ".Sonar" folder and throwing following exception 

ERROR: Caused by: Cannot find the assembly "D:\raj\MKS\VS\
MKS\.sonarqube\bin\sonar-runner\bin\raj\MKS\VS\MKS\bin\Debug\ABC.dll" provided by the property "sonar.cs.fxcop.assembly".

I am not sure why is this so ?

Answer (score 1):

I was executing "msbuildsonarrunner"  commands ( begin, msbuild , end ) from normal command prompt. Normal command prompt is configured with MsBuild path ( i.e. C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\12.0\Bin). When I fire MsBuild command, Build is happening with No Fxcop Analysis. Then I checked same with Visual studio developer command prompt. Yes, Fxcop analysis is happening. I checked further to know how Visual studio command prompt is configured. In properties of VS Developer command prompt, I see Target as [ "%comspec% /k ""C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\Tools\VsDevCmd.bat"" ].

Then I switch back to normal command prompt and fired following command. 
CALL "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\Tools\VsDevCmd.bat". Then it started behaving as VS developer command prompt ( but obvious). It started Fxcop analysis when I fired MsBuild Command.

MsBuild command log of my dummy project is given below. I have included CA1823 fxcop rule in my quality profile. You can see warning in build log ( bold one) as I intentionally violated it.

Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 12.0.21005.1
[Microsoft .NET Framework, version 4.0.30319.34209]
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Build started 10/13/2015 12:20:14 PM.
Project "D:\SonarQubeProjects\Fibanocci\Fibanocci\Fibanocci.csproj" on node 1 (default targets).
GenerateTargetFrameworkMonikerAttribute:
Skipping target "GenerateTargetFrameworkMonikerAttribute" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
CoreCompile:
Skipping target "CoreCompile" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
_CopyAppConfigFile:
Skipping target "_CopyAppConfigFile" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
CopyFilesToOutputDirectory:
  Fibanocci -> D:\SonarQubeProjects\Fibanocci\Fibanocci\bin\Debug\Fibanocci.exe
OverrideCodeAnalysisProperties:
  Running FxCop analysis using the SonarQube ruleset. Ruleset: D:\SonarQubeProjects\Fibanocci\Fibanocci.sonarqube\conf\SonarQubeFxCop-cs.ruleset
RunCodeAnalysis:
  Running Code Analysis...
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Team Tools\Static Analysis Tools\FxCop\FxCopCmd.exe  /outputCulture:1033 /out:"bin\Debug\Fibanocci.exe.CodeAnalysisLog.xml" /file:"bin\Debug\Fibanocci.exe" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.5.1\Microsoft.CSharp.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.5.1\mscorlib.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.5.1\System.Core.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.5.1\System.Data.DataSetExtensions.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.5.1\System.Data.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.5.1\System.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.5.1\System.Xml.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.5.1\System.Xml.Linq.dll" /directory:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.5.1" /ruleSet:"=D:\SonarQubeProjects\Fibanocci\Fibanocci.sonarqube\conf\SonarQubeFxCop-cs.ruleset" /rulesetdirectory:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Team Tools\Static Analysis Tools\Rule Sets" /rule:"-C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Team Tools\Static Analysis Tools\FxCop\Rules" /searchgac /ignoreinvalidtargets /forceoutput /successfile /ignoregeneratedcode /saveMessagesToReport:Active /timeout:120 
**MSBUILD : warning CA1823: Microsoft.Performance : It appears that field 'Program.obj' is never used or is only ever assigned to. Use this field or remove it.** [D:\SonarQubeProjects\Fibanocci\Fibanocci\Fibanocci.csproj]
  Code Analysis Complete -- 0 error(s), 1 warning(s)
SetStyleCopAnalysisSettings:
  Setting 'sonar.stylecop.projectFilePath' to 'D:\SonarQubeProjects\Fibanocci\Fibanocci\Fibanocci.csproj'
WriteSonarQubeProjectData:
  Directory "D:\SonarQubeProjects\Fibanocci\Fibanocci.sonarqube\out\Fibanocci__AnyCPU_Debug_635803356164104589" doesn't exist. Skipping.
  Creating directory "D:\SonarQubeProjects\Fibanocci\Fibanocci.sonarqube\out\Fibanocci__AnyCPU_Debug_635803356164104589".
Done Building Project "D:\SonarQubeProjects\Fibanocci\Fibanocci\Fibanocci.csproj" (default targets).

Build succeeded.

"D:\SonarQubeProjects\Fibanocci\Fibanocci\Fibanocci.csproj" (default target) (1) ->
(RunCodeAnalysis target) -> 
  MSBUILD : warning CA1823: Microsoft.Performance : It appears that field 'Program.obj' is never used or is only ever assigned to. Use this field or remove it. [D:\SonarQubeProjects\Fibanocci\Fibanocci\Fibanocci.csproj]

```
1 Warning(s)
0 Error(s)
```

Time Elapsed 00:00:01.82

It worked !!! but landed me in another problem. These issues are not getting posted to Sonar server. DashBoard is showing 0 issues, though I see Fxcop warnings in analysis results.

Comment: About the issues not posted, I've resolved recreating the quality profiles, even if they have the same rules. I think that some rules changed their configuration from values with decimals to integer values (e.g. "comment density" from 65.0 to 65).